# Unable to find any Specflow Templates in VS2010

Tags: specflow

I am tring to start specflow 1.9 Visual Studio IDE integration from Visual Studio Galary. After Installation I could not find any Templates @ Project or File level related to specflow. Can anyone tell me what I am missing or doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance,

Nilkant S. Desai

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved as Issue was I have to refference that ticktack.scetchflow.dll into my project. As soon as I addd the refference I can see all Templates in Add new Item Dialogue.

Nilkanth S. Desai

Comment: Don't forget you can answer your own questions, and there's no penalty to doing so.

Comment: agree Jemes...@nilkanth if you get any solution,just write as answer and accept it as answer so in future it will be helpful for other too

Answer (score 0):

Google seems to think this is the best solution, but it doesn't help me as I have the same problem and referencing the DLL does nothing to help... until I rebuild the entire solution.

So if this doesn't work for you at first, remember you may need to explicitly rebuild the project referencing SpecFlow after you reference the ticktack.scetchflow.dll in it.